# Will my trusses hold Drywall and insulation

Tags: drywall, insulation, garage, truss

Our home was built in the 80’s located Southern California so during the different seasons it’s either really cold or super hot. Our garage has an open ceiling which I believe the tenants before just put drywall on the walls so no insulation anywhere. I know if we hang drywall and insulate we’ll need vents which doesn’t have either, but for now I just want to know if our bottom chords with metal gusset holding the joints will support the weight before anything is done. Total length is 22’ x 24’ ,22’ being the length of the bottom chord with 24” on center 2x4. Thanks in advanced

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is a very typical ceiling/roof truss configuration used in many homes everywhere in the USA. It will hold the sheetrock of your choice and any thickness of insulation you choose. If your garage is attached to your home, it is usually the same trusses over the living space

Comment: ok thanks i’ve tried to do some research but couldn’t find anyone with the same bottom chords where it’s jointed and just wanted to make sure

Comment: Those joining plates look like the weak link, but they are incredibly strong and bite into and hold the wood like a mad shark.  I know. I tried to remove one from an old truss.

Comment: Joints like that are common in truss chords. No worries on that front. A single board long enough to be the bottom chord is hard to come by, and the truss makes the loading simple, with the plates being engineered to handle the loading applied.